# Fancybox modal doesn't work inside iframe

Tags: iframe, modal-dialog

Fancybox modal dialog doesn't work in iPhone safari! Is there any reasons?

```
 <div class="m39-modal" data-component="m39-modal" id="modal_true">
    <button data-trigger="true" class="m39-modal__trigger">Modal Trigger</button>   
<div data-content="true" class="m39-modal__container" role="dialog" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="m39-modal__dialog">
        <div class="m39-modal__header">
            <div class="m39-modal__title">Terms &amp; Conditions</div>
            <button data-close="true" class="m39-modal__button--close">Close</button>
        </div>
        <div class="m39-modal__content">

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut facilisis metus, varius elementum leo. Sed ut justo at magna pulvinar commodo non quis elit. Etiam cursus turpis sagittis sapien vulputate, sed sagittis nisi interdum. Suspendisse id neque non elit feugiat luctus. Aenean venenatis iaculis gravida. Nulla consectetur luctus neque ut fermentum. Fusce tellus risus, laoreet lacinia purus sed, tempor interdum nunc. </p><p>Phasellus in lorem justo. Ut rhoncus turpis at arcu dapibus, at lacinia lacus elementum. Donec elementum consectetur justo, non hendrerit augue dictum sit amet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam fringilla dui eget orci fermentum, vitae porttitor massa mollis. Duis luctus, eros quis vulputate convallis, sapien neque condimentum neque, vitae fermentum turpis sapien in ligula.</p><p>Phasellus iaculis odio a urna hendrerit, in iaculis odio ultricies. Nunc sed lacinia nulla. Vestibulum malesuada nunc id sapien volutpat luctus. Nam non fermentum metus. Nullam fermentum massa ut sem tristique, sed rhoncus leo vestibulum. Nullam egestas faucibus hendrerit. Duis risus felis, pulvinar eget risus in, dapibus varius metus. Vivamus turpis magna, sodales ut consequat at, auctor eu orci.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can inspect the code on your iPhone safari, modal-dialog is not working, but on android it does. [If you tried to enter this link through your iphone with safari browser http://molham.ae/m39-modal.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSiUB.png)

if you click on (05) number popup should appear, if you try from desktop browser it does work.

Comment: Where is the fancybox (js) code?

Answer (score -1):

I am quite certain that the issue has to to with how Safari handles transitions. Could you add the following css rule in the page that the iframe loads and see if that fixes the error?

`.m39-modal .m39-modal__container, .m39-modal .m39-modal__dialog {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s;
}`